# Windows 7 not detecting graphics card (possible d3dim700.dll corruption)

Tags: windows-7

It's a laptop W520 with discrete NVidia Quadro 1000M graphics card. The video card does not get detected, the NVidia installer won't work because it is unable to identify it and dxdiag literally shows an empty name and n/a on other attributes in the display tab.

I ran sfc /scannow and it identified a (single) d3dim700.dll problem which it was unable to fix, here's part of the log from the C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log:

```
2013-01-08 23:25:20, Info                  CSI    000003a9 [SR] Verify complete
2013-01-08 23:25:20, Info                  CSI    000003aa [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2013-01-08 23:25:20, Info                  CSI    000003ab [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003ac Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-directx-direct3d_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_eb246466b6cc92e7\d3dim700.dll do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 b:LRbGhn3CNWApkBTbT0Rs1alscXVYc1EQJ6Juk4/RcxQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:P1tNvLwQjT5h0Z9uW49c274V5+e/eqkmdE//81rZS7M=}
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003ad [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-DirectX-Direct3D, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003ae Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-directx-direct3d_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_eb246466b6cc92e7\d3dim700.dll do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 b:LRbGhn3CNWApkBTbT0Rs1alscXVYc1EQJ6Juk4/RcxQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:P1tNvLwQjT5h0Z9uW49c274V5+e/eqkmdE//81rZS7M=}
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003af [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-DirectX-Direct3D, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003b0 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:202{101}]"Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.WindowsFoundationDelivery"
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003b1 Hashes for file member \??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dim700.dll do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 b:LRbGhn3CNWApkBTbT0Rs1alscXVYc1EQJ6Juk4/RcxQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:P1tNvLwQjT5h0Z9uW49c274V5+e/eqkmdE//81rZS7M=}
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003b2 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-directx-direct3d_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_eb246466b6cc92e7\d3dim700.dll do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll" :
  Found: {l:32 b:LRbGhn3CNWApkBTbT0Rs1alscXVYc1EQJ6Juk4/RcxQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:P1tNvLwQjT5h0Z9uW49c274V5+e/eqkmdE//81rZS7M=}
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003b3 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:48{24},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64"\[l:24{12}]"d3dim700.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
2013-01-08 23:25:21, Info                  CSI    000003b4 Repair results created:
```

With the key part being (i assume) that the .dll does not match the excpected hash of the file. I'd imagine reinstalling directx would solve this, but the microsoft installer is saying, that i already have the latest version and won't move on.

Answer (score 0):

Run the [Thinkvantage system Update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE).  It has found missing components a number of times for me.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

- Finding a way to reinstall DirectX. This thread ( http://forums.indiegamer.com/showthread.php?3265-Forcing-a-DirectX-reinstall ) seems to have some solutions.
- Running a Windows OS repair. Since DirectX is sort of part of the OS, perhaps this would help.
- Trying a third-party driver updater, such as those from this list: http://alternativeto.net/software/driver-genius/

I hope I managed to help.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to update using DirectX web installer runtime?
[Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `chkdsk /f` first, then try `sfc /scannow` again. Very strange that `sfc` isn't able to replace the file.